# Countdown is stopping when user is out of current tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I create a simple countdown with a "invert" progress bar - to control session in my website.

when time is over, page will be reload and without the session - blocked.

**ISSUE:**
The progress bar works fine - but IF the user change the window or the current tab - and "forgot" the page open - the countdown stops. I don't know why

**THE CODE:**

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, "linear");
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

progress(30, 30, $('#progressBar'));
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 0px;
  line-height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/2tonbd5k

Any idea to solve this?

I'm think I need to change the fixed "timeleft or timetotal" (+3Min) to a "real time" (user access the site at 21:57:00 then the "real time" to reload will be +3 minutes - 22:00:00 PM). If user go out, the animation will stop too - but when he returns the js will correct to the real time. I can update the "time" with ASP - but how I can do this?

** for test purposes timeleft in code is only 30s.

Comment: You'll want to run your time based on `localStorage.timeStamp = Date.now();`. Of course, seeing that you're trying to make a progress bar, why aren't you using an `xhr.onprogress` Event?

Comment: Browsers will suppress repeated timer operations in inactive windows to conserve cpu, memory etc

Comment: i.e. capture start time with `start = Date.now()` (no need for a Date object as such - also, no need to store anything in localStorage unless you want to preserve this time over page loads) - then  calculate time left by `Date.now() - start`

Comment: @JaromandaX good idea - but how the timer will know that it need to stop in 3 minutes?

Comment: timer continues while `Date.now() - start < 180000`

Comment: `if(localStorage.timeStamp+180001 > Date.now()){  /* three minutes have passed */ }`

Comment: tks @JaromandaX countdown works fine - the only issue is that the progress bar animation didn't update with the "real time" left.

Comment: using the methods outlined in these comments, it will

Comment: @StackSlave ... so if the timestamp is `1600133117909` (which is about now) ... then you would check if `localStorage.timeStamp + 18001 > Date.now()` ? hint: it will be ... always ... I'd test if `+localStorage.timeStamp + 180001 > Date.now()`

Comment: hi @JaromandaX can you check what I'm doing wrong please? :D - https://jsfiddle.net/2tonbd5k/2/ - If I stay in the tab works ok - but if I change the tab - countdown is over but the progress bar still with some time resting. (in the test I put the countdown with 30s)

Comment: you're almost there, but still calculating the progress bar width on the wrong thing - see https://jsfiddle.net/0zwt931d/

Comment: here's the same code without jquery - https://jsfiddle.net/0zwt931d/1/

Comment: Oh - and if you want silky smooth animation - https://jsfiddle.net/0zwt931d/2/

Comment: heheeh @JaromandaX tks a lot! the last with silky smooth animation didn't works here.. the first has a issue with long times (tested with 180s - if you go out of tab and return with 2 min - the animation still "full" - sometimes we have ZERO s and the bar still counting.But the code without jquery works F-A-N-T-A-S-T-I-C! inclusive with long times as 180s. really great!!!

Comment: That's really odd that the last one doesn't work and has weird issues like that - oh well - oh, remove the transition from the CSS :p

Comment: ohh great @JaromandaX !

Comment: Just seeing @JaromandaX comment. What? Obviously you wouldn't update the `localStorage.timeStamp = Date.now();` unless three minutes are passed or there is no `localStorage.timeStamp`.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is add this script

```
if ( document.hidden ) { return; }
```

the result is here
https://jsfiddle.net/mfkLea7w/